# Quelle est l'équivalence de « review paper » en français ?

Tags: vocabulaire, science

Pour une application web française je dois traduire le terme "Review Paper". Bien que je saisisse convenablement la signification de ce mot dans la langue de Shakespeare.

> A **research paper** is based on **original research**. The kind of research may vary depending on your field or the topic (experiments, survey, interview, questionnaire, etc.), but authors need to collect and analyze raw data and conduct an original study. The research paper will be based on the analysis and interpretation of this data.
>
> A **review article** or **review paper** is based on other published articles.
>   It does not report original research. Review articles generally
>   summarize the existing literature on a topic in an attempt to explain
>   the current state of understanding on the topic

Je n'ai pas la moindre idée de comment traduire ce terme pour qu'il garde, pour le public auquel il s'adresse, la bonne signification.

Quelle serait la meilleure traduction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'après [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revue_de_la_litt%C3%A9rature), `article de revue` existe. L'article propose `revue de la littérature` ou `analyse de la littérature`. Ces termes ne me disent rien mais je ne suis pas universitaire.

`État des lieux` me semble rendre la même idée mais ce n'est pas aussi précis que l'expression anglaise.

En tant qu'étudiant, quand on faisait ce genre de travail (donc pas dans un contexte d'édition universitaire), on appelait ça une `synthèse`.

Comment: +1 pour article de revue ou article de synthèse. Je n'ai par contre jamais rencontré "état des lieux" concernant une publication scientifique

Comment: @radouxju en fait je pense qu'`état de l'art` proposé par @Umaiki est bien meilleur.

Comment: Mon problème avec l'état de l'art, c'est que c'est un concept plus précis qu'une revue de la littérature. L'état de l'art se veut spécifique et vise à identifier l'état des connaissances au jour J. Il est attendu que la plupart des articles originaux débutent par un état de l'art, afin que leur originalité soit clairement identifiable. Un "review paper" est 1) toujours un article (et pas un chapitre dans un article) et 2) généralement plus exhaustif/historique qu'un "état de l'art".

Comment: Je conviens toutefois que c'est confus (même en anglais) et que certains considèrent les "états de l'art" comme une sous-catégorie de review paper, voire comme des synonymes. Mais sans doute est-ce lié au domaine dans lequel on travaille. J'appuie donc votre réponse  (même si j'avoue trouver qu'"état de l'art" "sonne" mieux) en vous félicitant pour votre remise en question.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que la traduction que tu cherches est `état de l'art` ou `dresser un état de l'art`.
Tout protocole de recherche dresse en amont un `état de l'art`. Ce qui correspond à agréger et à faire un résumé de tous les papiers de recherche concernant le sujet visé.

Je t'invite à lire le wiki pour voir si ça correspond à ce que tu cherches: [Etat de l'art](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tat_de_l%27art)

Comment: L'état de l'art correspond au "state of the art" anglais. Il s'agit plutôt de l'exercice de synthèse bibliographique qui est le constituant majeur de l'introduction d'un article original, pas d'un "review paper" en tant que tel.